# Jinja2 nested loop template for processing Ansible YAML variables from two lists

Tags: python, ansible, nested, jinja2

I am first month to automation and ansible, going through all the learning curve and yet I have a task on which I have spent several good days
trying to figure out without a big progress so far, so I would be very thankful for any tips & tricks.

I have YAML file with variables in Ansible all_vars.yml code waiting to be ran in the role, example below:

```
pg_hba:
  - section: "DEFAULT"
    entries:
      - { type: local, database: all, user: all, auth_method: trust }
      - { type: host, database: all, user: all, address: 127.0.0.1/32, auth_method: trust }
      - { type: host, database: all, user: all, address: 174.34.2.0/24, auth_method: md5, comment: "Private Wifi" }
  - section: "DBA"
    entries:
      - { type: host, database: all, user: all, address: 192.168.2.130/32, auth_method: md5, comment: "Name" }
      - { type: host, database: all, user: all, address: 174.34.2.156/32, auth_method: md5, comment: "Name" }
```

And the output processed format in the Jinja2 template is approx. like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE   USER           CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD #
######
# DEFAULT
######

{% for client in pg_hba %}
{{ '{:10}'.format(client.type) }} {{ '{:15}'.format(client.database) }} {{ '{:20}'.format(client.user) }} {{ '{:20}'.format(client.address|default('')) }} {{ '{:10}'.format(client.auth_method) }} {% if client.comment is defined %} # {{ client.comment|default("") }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if replication_group is defined %}

# REPLICATION
##########

{% for item in groups[ replication_group ] %}
{{ '{:10}'.format("host") }} {{ '{:15}'.format("replication") }} {{ '{:20}'.format("postgres") }} {{ '{:20}'.format(hostvars[item].ansible_default_ipv4.address+"/32") }} {{ '{:10}'.format("trust") }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Output, rendered expected example:

```
# DEFAULT
######
local       all                all                                                         trust
host        all                all                           127.0.0.1/32          trust 
host        all                all                           174.34.2.0/24         md5    # Private WiFi

# REPLICATION
#########
host       replication     postgres             174.34.2.14/32       trust
```

The issue is, the sample without multiple sections and multiple entries list works fine, like if we leave only one list under pg_hba with 3 entries items, without sub-directories and process it via Jinja2, but when I try to apply similiar logic to do nested loop (at least it seems to me) for ansible code above and try to iterate each section and then the entry inside, I am unable to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template below iterate nested loops

```
{% for item in pg_hba %}
{% if item.section == 'DEFAULT' %}
#########
# DEFAULT
#########
{% for client in item.entries %}
{{ '{:10}'.format(client.type) }} {{ '{:15}'.format(client.database) }} {{ '{:20}'.format(client.user) }} {{ '{:20}'.format(client.address|default('')) }} {{ '{:10}'.format(client.auth_method) }} {% if client.comment is defined %} # {{ client.comment|default("") }}{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for item in pg_hba %}
{% if item.section == 'DBA' %}
#####
# DBA
#####
{% for client in item.entries %}
{{ '{:10}'.format(client.type) }} {{ '{:15}'.format(client.database) }} {{ '{:20}'.format(client.user) }} {{ '{:20}'.format(client.address|default('')) }} {{ '{:10}'.format(client.auth_method) }} {% if client.comment is defined %} # {{ client.comment|default("") }}{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

gives

```
#########
# DEFAULT
#########
local      all             all                                       trust      
host       all             all                  127.0.0.1/32         trust      
host       all             all                  174.34.2.0/24        md5         # Private Wifi

#####
# DBA
#####
host       all             all                  192.168.2.130/32     md5         # Name
host       all             all                  174.34.2.156/32      md5         # Name
```

Is this what are you looking for?

Comment: Thank you! "{% for client in item.entries %}" par was the exactly which one helped me alot and to construct the rest of iteration.